# Жор памяти Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем, ситуация такая. Есть скрипт `MainMenu`, подвешен на `MainCamera`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngineInternal;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject canvas;
public GameObject background;
public GameObject button;

GameObject panelMainMenu;

void Start()
{
    panelMainMenu = Instantiate(canvas) as GameObject;
    GameObject background = CreateBackground(0,0,1920,1080,panelMainMenu) as GameObject;        
}

public GameObject CreateBackground(float posX, float posY, float sizeX, float sizeY, GameObject parent)
{
    GameObject back = Instantiate(background, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    back.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
    back.transform.localScale = new Vector3(sizeX, sizeY, 1);
    back.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posX, posY, 0);
    return back;
}
}
```

`canvas, background, button` - стандартные UI элементы, прикрепленные через инспектор. После запуска сцены начинается неистовый жор памяти приложением Unity, в результате чего, если не успеть закрыть процесс, кладется вся система. В чем может быть причина? 
В сцене присутствуют только `MainCamera` и `EventSystem`.

Comment: С данным скриптом Жориков не замечено........следовательно проблема не в этом.....прям никаких скриптов ни к чему больше не прикреплено? где есть update или fixedUdpdate или IEnumerator и т.д.? Никаких скриптов в папке Editor которые работают с текущими классами? версия юнити какая?

Comment: Да, я сам потестил в другом проекте, все работает. Объектов и скриптов в сцене нет, кроме вышеописанного, версия 5.2.0f3.

Comment: Попробуйте значит пересоздать новый проект и делать в нем

Answer (score 5):

На сколько мне помнится у нас была подобная проблема с этой версией (5.2.0) Unity, при работе с UI память очень быстро переполнялась и приложение падало. Лечили это установка последнего патча для этой версии.  Попробуйте поставить патчи (мы ставили 3 если не ошибаюсь), а лучше обновитесь до последней версии, скорей всего проблема решится.